# How to effeciently return a subarray by key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following structure:

```
myArr: [
  {
    key1: 'foo',
    myArr: [
      { a: 'blah' }
      { a: 'blah2'}
    ],
  },
  {
    key1: 'foo2',
  }
  ...More similar entries
];
```

I am looking for an efficient way to extract the sub arrays into a separate array.  The sub arrays have the same key as the parent. The sub arrays may or may not exist.

I can iterate through them in a loop and manually add them to a new array if they exist.

I would prefer to use some sort of map/filter if it's possible to do in this particular case.

The result I am after is:

```
myArr: [
  { a: 'blah' },
  { a: 'blah2'},
  { a: 'blahN'}
],
```

Comment: Your example isn't complete enough to give a good answer. Could `foo2` also have a `myArr` element. If so, do you want to concatenate them? Is the data structure always only one level deep? Are there other keys like `myArr` with similarly named subarrays that you need to find. It's hard to know how general or specific the answer should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slick way to accomplish this would just be to reduce the initial array:

```
let result = myArr.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b.myArr || []), []);
```

That starts with an empty array and just concats the selected property into it, resulting in a single array of objects. If the subarray is `undefined` or otherwise falsy, we can `concat` an empty array (which will not actually add anything to the original array)